# 1Password for Mac - pricing

Tags: passwords, 1password

I am just starting to look into 1Password for password management and I am already confused. Why is the app $35 to download from the Mac App Store yet it is a free download for Mac on their website? It doesn't seem to be any different?

Comment: 1Password is "Try before you buy" as mentioned on their site: The Mac and Windows products available on our website come with an unlimited demonstration period so you can "Try Before You Buy". [link](https://agilebits.com/home/licenses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app you download from the AgileBits website will need to be licensed - if you don't buy a license it will not work (though it will offer you a 30 day demo).

The detailed differences between the App Store version and the AgileBits website version are detailed in this [AgileBits support document](https://guides.agilebits.com/1password-mac-kb/4/en/topic/mas-vs-agile-store).

Comment: The link is dead, could you correct it please?